# Frequency of order pair in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have two row vectors in Matlab, say X and Y (both of same size). now i want to find the frequency of order pair (x,y). How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to find the unique pairs and their occurances

```
[C, ia, ic] = unique( [X Y], 'rows' );
n = hist( ic, 1:size(C,1) ); % count the pairs
freq = n ./ sum(n);
```

Comment: i didn't get your last command. I want the frequency of each order pair of C in [X Y]

Comment: @sahil - best way: run in  debug mode and see what happens. `ic` stores the row indices of the unique pairs (mapping from `C` to `[X Y]`). `hist` command counts the frequency of each unique index, thus returning in `n` the number of occurrences of each pair.

Comment: So what i should be getting is no. of rows in n same as no. of rows in C as each row should tell the frequency of the corresponding pair in C. But what I am receiving is: size(C):821 x 2  and size(n): 1 x 1642